# How do you move multiple faces by equal increments?

Tags: modeling

I have a cog wheel and I want to make the spokes a bit longer than they are. I can select the tip of one and drag it out a bit, but how do I precisely measure how much I've moved something so that I can then move all the other tips the same distance?

I can't have uneven cog spokes.

[image]

Comment: Can you use array modifier for the cogs? that will be the best option for symmetrical objects

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**For symmetrical shapes the best method is to use array modifier.**

Delete all the faces leaving only one cog then change to object mode and add an empty in the origin of the gear and rotate the empty 45 degrees.

[image]

Then add array modifier on the gear object, set count to 8, disable **Relative Offset**. Then enable **Object Offset** and select empty from the selection box and enable **Merge** and **First and Last.**

[image]

This way you can control the gear shape by modifying only on cog.

[image]

Comment: I have created an addon to do that a lot faster,you can use it in this condition.
https://github.com/emaema/procedural-dupli-spin
read the documentation if you dont know how to use it.

Comment: Does the 'merge' ensure that vertices are merged when they touch so that the resulting mesh isn't a bunch of overlapping but disconnected edges?

Comment: @leigero Yes it will merge the vertices that are within the specified distance from eachother

Answer (score 4):

Blender can move more than one face at once by various means.

- You can extrude more than one face at time.  Be in `Face Select` mode.  Depicted in the image below (vertex, edge, face enabled).  Select your faces.  Use <kbd>shift</kbd> + click.  Then <kbd>E</kbd> to extrude. <kbd>Return</kbd> Key. Selection is still there. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> to move face on normals (See menu Mesh/Transfrom/Shrink Fatten).

[image]

- If you want to casually work, you can place a cylinder around the cog as a circular guide.
- The same circular guide can be used as target for shrink wrap modifier.  You must create a vertex group for the faces on the teeth of the cog.
  Shrink Wrap  can be applied:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Wonderful keystroke editing by another author.

Answer (score 4):

You can precisely define the value of any element's movement. After pressing <kbd>G</kbd>, <kbd>S</kbd> or <kbd>R</kbd> and selecting the desired transformation axis (press <kbd>x</kbd>,<kbd>y</kbd> or <kbd>z</kbd>) you may input the number from the numerical keyboard. As pictured below I selected the edge of the spoke, pressed <kbd>G</kbd>, then <kbd>Y</kbd> and then 0.2
[image]

Select all the spoke's edges and press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>*-->Snap-->Cursor to Selected*. It will place the cursor in the center. Set the pivot point type to a *3D Cursor*. Press <kbd>S</kbd> and input the desired transformation value. You may also enable the ***Snap Tool*** (click the magnet icon, and change the snapping type to *Increment*). It will allow you to increase the spoke's lenght very precisely while scaling (hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> while scaling and you'll be able to change the lenght's value in smaller increments).
[image]

Now change the pivot point type to *Individual Origins*.
[image]

Press <kbd>S</kbd> and input the desired value to make all the spokes scale the same way.
[image]