# How to do a wrist watch button

Tags: mesh

The watch button has those details and i'm no really sure how to do them.
[image]

[image]

Comment: You could try using a cylinder and add enough edges, bevel every other edge and push them down with alt

Comment: related [Extruding outward from center point to create the Bottle Cap Grip](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43883/extruding-outward-from-center-point-to-create-the-bottle-cap-grip/43900#43900)

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46284/whats-the-most-elegant-way-to-cut-shapes-out-of-a-mesh/ and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31134/how-do-you-move-multiple-faces-by-equal-increments also see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/9224/creating-clock-cogs/